# python-plotly-boxplot Why not showing the max and minimum value on graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot, plotly

This is my data:[0, 45, 47, 46, 47,47,43,100].
And picture looks like this:
https://plot.ly/~zfrancica/8/

I want to have a picture like this: https://plot.ly/~zfrancica/9/
(an out come picture of [0, 45, 47, 46, 100] )

I want to have a fixed 0 minimum and 100 maximum.(May be this is not the correct box plot but I want to fix the minimum and maximum.) How should I do this?

(If ploty can't do this, a matplotlib plot code would also be fine.)
My code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

def box_plot(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
    num = len(kwargs['circum'])
    #WornPercentage = go.Box(x=kwargs['circum'])
    #data = [WornPercentage]

    #py.iplot(data)

    data = [
        go.Box(
            x=kwargs['circum'],
            boxpoints='all',
            jitter=0.3,
            pointpos=-1.8
        )
    ]
    py.iplot(data)



process_dict={'circum':[0, 45, 47, 46, 47,47,43,100]}
box_plot(**process_dict)
```

Comment: I've checked the second link you have written in your question but it seems the link is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

#### Credentials

For those who don't know how to save credentials permanently;

```
import plotly.tools as tls
tls.set_credentials_file(username='username', api_key='api-key')
```

Assuming you have already saved your credentials;

#### A - Simple Solution

For a single one dimensional data;

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace0 = go.Box(
    y=[0, 45, 47, 46, 47, 47, 43, 100], # Data provided
    name = 'Provided Data Chart',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'        # Blue : #0000FF
    )
)

data = [trace0]
py.plot(data)                           # Using plot instead of iplot
```

#### A - Output

[image]

#### B - Using Layout

And you can also check this out for a nicer layout, there is a `range` option you can use, for when `autorange` is set to `False`;

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import Layout
from plotly.graph_objs import Font
from plotly.graph_objs import YAxis
from plotly.graph_objs import Figure

trace0 = go.Box(
    y=[0, 45, 47, 46, 47, 47, 43, 100], # Data provided
    name = 'Provided Data Chart',
    marker = dict(
        color = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'        # Blue : #00FF00
    )
)

data = [trace0]

layout = Layout(
    autosize=True,
    font=Font(
        family='"Droid Sans", sans-serif'
    ),
    height=638,
    title='Plotly Box Demo',
    width=1002,
    yaxis=YAxis(
        autorange=False,                # Autorange set to False
        range=[0, 100],                 # Custom Range
        title='Y units',                # To be changed, units
        type='linear'                   # Use 'log' for appropriate data
    )
)

fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plot_url = py.plot(fig)                 # Using plot instead of iplot
```

#### B - Output

[image]

Hope that it helps.